# Gravity Forms - show field entries as a live preview

Tags: wordpress, forms, gravityforms

Does anyone knows how I can "call" individual field entries and display them in the same page, in real-time, with Gravity Forms? I can easily do that with another form builder I have, but I prefer to use GF.

Here is a demo of a very simple form I'm trying to create with this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dN0yo.png)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is the Live Merge Tags feature of the Gravity Forms Populate Anything add-on:

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/#live-merge-tags